# How can I set the lockscreen personal message after updating?

Tags: lock-screens, 4.3-jelly-bean

On my Samsung Galaxy S3, I had an option to change the personal message on the lock screen. After the system update,  the option is still there, but it is grayed out. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a lock screen set? Or is it None?

Comment: its just the swipe

Answer (score 1):

Swipe to an empty lock screen, press the "+" button and add messaging. That should do it.

If it still doesn't work try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.celltick.lockscreen).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings >> My Device >> Home Screen Mode and change it to "Standard Mode". That should enable the personal message option on your lock screen...